# navigation and bootstrap is not working in chrome but works well with Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my website in this mobile and tablet device condition works good in firefox but not in `chrome` can i have a solution for this.

Even i added extra CSS for navigation for mobile and tablet condition

```
i.e min width 320 to max width 480

and min width 768 to max width 1024
```

but this doesn't work with chrome

http://yourdemozone.com/kbl/html/

Answer (score 0):

put some margin-top on your `ul`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 30px;">
```